# SQL*plus variable column heading

Tags: sqlplus

Is there a way in SQL*Plus to define headings from variables retrieved from a table?

Would like to be able to display a conditional column heading, based on the values stored in a table, in SQL*plus.

The report is by customer and each customer has different headings stored in a table. The format of the columns is the same for all customers, only the headings are different.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables